# Converting every .flac files in a folder into 320kbps .mp3 without losing metadata

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert every .flac files in a folder into 320kbps .mp3 without losing metadata

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i *.flac -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 *.mp3
```

but it returns: `*.flac: Invalid argument`

What I would like to do is to convert every flac files into 320kbps mp3 without losing metadata

Thanks.

Comment: "Invalid argument" appears to be an ffmpeg error with the command line; my guess from looking at the documentation ( https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html ) is that it cannot take a wildcard parameter for `-i`, and instead needs `-i file1.flac -i file2.flac`, etc. since a wildcard is not shown in any of the examples there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This do seem to be doable with a simple loop on the Get-ChildItem, like...

```
PS C:\Users> Get-ChildItem *.flac | % {
  $mp3filename = $_.basename + '.mp3'
  ffmpeg -i $_.filename -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 $mp3filename
}
```

This also seems to deal with the "no wildcard" problem mentioned in the comments

Comment: You should be consequent and **use** the variable name you just created ;-) or just `ffmpeg -i $_.filename -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 ($_.basename + '.mp3')`

Comment: I have no idea what happened there! Thanks @LotPings

Answer (score 2):

Try this in CMD:

```
for %A IN (*.flac) DO ffmpeg -i "%A" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 %~nA.mp3
```

Comment: In case of spaces in the file name I'd use double quotes both times: `"%~nA.mp3"`

Answer (score 2):

In bash this could be easily done:

```
for f in *.flac;do ffmpeg -i "${f}" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "${f%.*}".mp3;done;
```

Answer (score 1):

This PS code should work from the current directory recursively. just change $ffpath to where your ffmpeg is.

```
$inProcessPath = $pwd.path;
$flacfiles = Get-ChildItem -Include @("*.flac") -Path $inProcessPath -Recurse;
$ffpath = 'c:\temp\ffmpeg.exe';

foreach ($flacfile in $flacfiles) {
    $mp3file = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($flacfile.FullName, '.mp3')
    $ArgumentList = '-i "{0}" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -write_id3v1 1 -id3v2_version 3 "{1}"' -f $flacfile, $mp3file;
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object $ArgumentList;
    Start-Process $ffpath -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
}
```